# How to pass multiple arguments to foreach from a file

Tags: expect

I have a file which contains a list of Servers ( space ) User and now I want to pass this file as an argument to my expect script so that my script will spawn an ssh session to user@server and execute a bunch of commands and exit.

```
cat HostsUserFile.txt 

Server1 User1
Server2 User2
Server3 User3

cat CollectStats.exp

### Get the list of hosts, one per line, whereas hosts.txt should be a file    containing the list of servers and user #####
set password ****
set f [open "HostsUserFile.txt"]
set hosts [split [read -nonewline $f] "\n"]
close $f

### Loop through the hosts listed in host.txt ###
foreach { host user } $hosts {
### spawn ssh process ###
spawn -noecho ssh -q $user@$host -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
expect "*?assword*"
send "$password\r"
expect "*$*"
send "exit\r"
}
```

I want Server1 to be substituted to host and User1 to be substituted to user variable during 1st iteration and so on.

Please help me to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the variable `hosts` is a list of list, (i.e.`{Server1 User1} {Server2 User2} {Server3 User3}`) you should use single variable for the `foreach` loop and inside that you can extract the items as

```
foreach hostinfo $hosts {
    # If your 'Tcl' version is 8.5 or above, use lassign as, 
    #           lassign $hostinfo server user
    # Else, use 'lindex' to get this done
    set server [lindex $hostinfo 0]
    set user [lindex $hostinfo 1]
    puts "Server : $server , User : $user"

    # Your further code on ssh
}
```